# Почему не создаются PDF и прочие файлы в R?

Tags: r, atom

Недавно начал пользоваться R, пару дней назад (вроде бы) получилось создать PDF файл, сейчас он пустой (я не помню, был ли он с графиком, вроде БЫЛ!), открывается как текстовый. То же самое с любыми файлами, которые я пытаюсь создать (PNG, jpg вообще не создаются даже), каждый раз в результате гидроген выдает [NULL]. Работаю в АТОМ с hydrogen. R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock". Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Спасибо за любую помощь! Пробовал в #.

```
setwd('/home/.../Documents/program_with_r/stat-learning/data')
Auto = read.csv('Auto.csv', header = T, na.strings="?" )
fix(Auto)
Auto = na.omit(Auto)
summary(Auto)
attach(Auto)
lm.fit = lm(mpg ~ horsepower)
summary(lm.fit)
predict(lm.fit, data.frame(horsepower=c(98)), interval = "confidence")
predict(lm.fit, data.frame(horsepower=c(95)), interval = "prediction")
plot(horsepower, mpg) + abline(lm.fit,col = "red")
plot(Auto)
library('ggplot2')
plot(Auto)
pdf("Auto_pdf.pdf")
dev.off()
#print(plot(Auto)) + pdf("Rplot.pdf")
#dev.off()
#gf <- as.data.frame(Auto)
#pdf("ggplot3.pdf") + ggplot(gf)
#dev.off()
#pdf("Rplot1.pdf") + plot(Auto)
#dev.off()

capabilities()
''' 
jpegTRUEpngTRUEtiffTRUEtcltkTRUEX11TRUEaquaFALSEhttp/ftpTRUEsocketsTRUElibxmlTRUEfifoTRUEcleditFALSEiconvTRUENLSTRUEprofmemTRUEcairoTRUEICUTRUElong.doubleTRUElibcurlTRUE
'''
```

Comment: запустите программу: `$ R`, и выполните первую из команд: `Auto = read.csv('Auto.csv', header = T, na.strings="?" )`. есть ошибки? вот про них и задавайте вопрос.

Comment: у меня выбрана setwd(home/....)
я ее не добавил т.к кому какое дело где у меня лежат файлы, но ок сейчас добавлю, у меня проблема что Р создает пустой ломанный PDF файл

Comment: поменяйте местами команды назначения выходного устройства `pdf("Auto_pdf.pdf")` и собственно рисования в это устройство: `plot(Auto)`. если всё равно ничего не получилось, начните с начала: `$ r -e 'pdf("1.pdf");plot(mtcars);dev.off()'`. должен создаться файл `1.pdf` с примерно такой [картинкой](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/images/scatterplot_matrices.png) (только квадратов будет побольше).

Comment: все дело в том, что в консоли это работает!Но когда я например хочу поменять директорию для сохранения файла он выдает ошибку "нельзя сменить директорию", это консоль. А в ATOM-editor, постоянно создает ломанный PDF с ничем внутри. Сам PDF он создает, сохраняет - битым файлом.

Comment: кхм. да при чём тут вообще какой-то редактор? вам скрипт нужно исполнить. с помощью интерпретатора `$ r` (`$ R` — это интерактивный режим). создать скрипт вы можете, конечно, средствами любого понравившегося вам текстового редактора, но интерпретировать-то его должен не редактор, а интерпретатор: `$ r путь.к.файлу.со.скриптом`

Comment: `когда я например хочу поменять директорию для сохранения файла он выдает ошибку "нельзя сменить директорию"` — а с этого места поподробнее, пожалуйста. опишите ваши действия, приводящие к выводу такой ошибки. вообще указать можно и полный и относительный путь: `pdf("/абсолютный/путь/к/Auto_pdf.pdf")` / `pdf("относительный/путь/к/Auto_pdf.pdf")`

Comment: $R ; getwd() : "/home/iakov"; setwd("home/iakov/Documents/program_with_r/") : невозможно сменить рабочий каталог; 
все дело в том, что в атом используется hydrogen (аналог jupyter-kernel), который позволяет исполнять код в редакторе, таким образом я почти не пользовался console $R, и в console $R при попытке создать name_file.pdf, все работает, когда в atom + hydrogen = нет, таким образом ошибка лежит в самом hydrogen, как я теперь понимаю. Но насчет смены директории я все же не понимаю что делаю не так :)

Comment: ну нет у вас такого каталога `/home/iakov/home/iakov/Documents/program_with_r`. укажите или абсолютный путь: `/home/iakov/Documents/program_with_r/`, или относительный (относительно текущего каталога, который в этот момент у вас — `/home/iakov`): `Documents/program_with_r`

Comment: сработало! спасибо большое)